# How to assign value to a textbox that is created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a row which has a add button.On click of add rows get added dynamically and on click of del rows will be deleted.
Row consists of collection of drop downs,text boxes.
One text box has to be prepopulated with a value based on user input in previous text box in the same row.

Able to prepopulate value in the textbox only for the first row.For the dynamic rows textbox is not getting prepopulated. Getting values from DB but not printing value in the textbox.

Following is my code:

```
$("tr.dynamicRow").each(function() {
    var studentCreate = $(this).find('#studentCreate').val();//textbox which gets added dynamically
    // AJAX to get values from DB and this works fine and the value is stored in result variable
    if (result != "" && result !=null) {                     
         $(this).find('#studentCreateNew').attr('value',result);//this doesn't work
    }
});
```

HTML code:

```
<tr class= "dynamicRow">
//some drop downs
    <div class="inputField">
        <td><b><bean:message key="label.student.create" />:</b></td>
        <td ><html:text property="studentCreate" name="studentForm" styleId="studentCreate" onchange="populateStudentCreate(this);" size="10" maxlength="6"  ></html:text></td>
    </div>
                                
    <div class="inputField">
        <td>    
            <b><bean:message key="label.student.create" />:</b>
        </td>
        <td><html:text property="studentCreateNew" name="studentForm" styleId="studentCreateNew" size="10" maxlength="6"></html:text></td>
//Add button
</tr>
```

Kindly help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: IDs need to be unique throughout the whole document, maybe thats the issue

Comment: Please share enough code to show exactly how you're adding the ajax content and at what point the user provides the content for the textbox.

Comment: I used alert statements to check if I'm getting the correct values using $(this).ID.I got it correct.

Comment: Edited to show enough code.

Comment: HTML code :<div class="inputField">
          <td><b><bean:message key="label.student.create" />:</b></td>
          <td ><html:text property="studentCreate" name="studentForm" styleId="studentCreate" onchange="populateStudentCreate(this);" size="10" maxlength="6"   >
          </html:text></td>
         </div>
         
         <div class="inputField">
         <td> 
         <b><bean:message key="label.student.create" />:</b>
         </td>
         <td><html:text property="studentCreateNew" name="studentForm" styleId="studentCreateNew" >
         </html:text></td>

Comment: Javascript code : function populateStudentCreate(element){
    
    $("tr.dynamicRow").each(function() {
      var studentCreate = $(this).find('#studentCreate').val();
    if (studentCreate != 0 || studentCreate !='') {
   var params = 'studentCreate='+studentCreate;
   params     = encodeURI(params);
      var jqxhr  = jQuery.ajax({
       success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
                             if (result != "" && result !=null) { 
                               $(this).find('#studentCreateNew').val(result);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
`$(this).find('#studentCreate').attr('value',result);'`
you could try
`$(this).find('#studentCreate').append('<p>'+result+'</p>);`

Comment: Thank you. I tried using its not working! Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Using `#studentCreate` is likely not what's getting generated, or there are more than one of them.  If you can assign a unique class to every element you want to target:

```
$("tr.dynamicRow td input.studentCreate")
```

For instance, to select the input field directly.  Then you don't need to parse directly from the row.

Additionally, question: the markup doesn't list a TR around the TD tags, but a DIV.  Is that the correct markup?  Is there a sample where it includes the TR tab with the dynamicRow class?

Comment: Edited my question  and now it includes dynamicRow class belonging <tr>.Sorry I didn't get your answer.Can you please tell me what to edit.

Comment: So for whatever renders html:text, is there a way you can set a css class on it?  that way, you can use the dot notation like $("tr.dynamicRow .studentCreate") to find all the instances, for instance.